# Access Vector of Vectors <double*>

Tags: c++, vector

I am having trouble accessing the saved doubles in my vector < vector <*double>>.
I am reading a .txt file and saving the values stored in it (which should constitute a matrix) in my vector of vectors.

```
vector <vector<double*>> HypMean;

ifstream myFile;
myFile.open(nameOfFile);

if (myFile.is_open() && myFile.good()) {
string line;    
while(getline(myFile, line)){    //Get line-by-line in file

    istringstream buffer(line);
    string value;
    int numLoop = 0;
    vector <double*> tempVector;

    while (getline (buffer, value, ',')){       //Get character by character in line
        istringstream valuebuffer(value);
        tempVector.push_back(new double[1]);
        valuebuffer >> *(tempVector.back() + numLoop);

        cout << *(tempVector.back() + numLoop) << " ";

        numLoop++;
    }

    HypMean.push_back(tempVector);
    cout << endl;
}   
myFile.close(); 
}
```

This is my function, and I guess I am saving the values right since when I am printing the "tempVector" while creating it and it works.

```
0.014872 0.078519 0.071838 -0.10371
-0.16741 -0.0063904 0.0018366 0.21238
0.13796 -0.29323 0.23489 -0.074523
```

However, when I try to access the whole thing (HypMean), I don't know how to do it. I have tried the following with no luck:

```
for (int x=0; x<3; x++){
     for (int y=0; y<4; y++){
        cout << *(HypMean[x][y]) << " ";
 }
 cout<<endl;
```

}

```
0.014872 -6.27744e+66 -6.27744e+66 -6.27744e+66
-0.16741 -6.27744e+66 -6.27744e+66 -6.27744e+66
0.13796 -6.27744e+66 -6.27744e+66 -6.27744e+66
```

Any ideas please? What should I change to access it properly?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why `new double[1]`?? Why not simply  `vector <vector<double>> HypMean;`??

Comment: Yep, using `new` is completely superfluous here. Also, using array `new` to allocate a single element doesn't make sense. If you happen to have a background in C# or Java, don't use their style of `new` use in C++!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that in these lines you are writing to and reading from some random piece of memory:

```
valuebuffer >> *(tempVector.back() + numLoop);
cout << *(tempVector.back() + numLoop) << " ";
```

After the call to `push_back`, `tempVector.back()` is a reference to the last element in `tempVector` which is a pointer to the first element in an array of `double` of size 1. If you add `numLoop` to that pointer you get some random piece of memory off the end of that array of `double`.

You can "fix" it by changing those lines to:

```
valuebuffer >> *tempVector.back();
cout << *tempVector.back() << " ";
```

However, there is no good reason why you are allocating an array of `double` of size 1. Instead of a `std::vector<std::vector<double*>>`. It would be much simpler to just have a `std::vector<std::vector<double>>` instead which you could fill with something like:

```
tempVector.push_back(0.0);
valuebuffer >> tempVector.back();
```

You could then read the 2D vector with:

```
for (int x=0; x<3; x++){
    for (int y=0; y<4; y++){
        cout << HypMean[x][y] << " ";
    }
    cout<<endl;
}
```

Or better yet,

```
for (const auto& v : HypMean){
    for (auto value : v) {
        cout << value << " ";
    }
    cout<<endl;
}
```

[Live demo.](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/2DBTJFitY18mSnbZ)

Comment: That is exactly what I needed! @Chris Drew Thanks a lot everything makes sense now!